# Asociar elemento de dos listas y eliminar el menor si esta duplicado

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo dos listas:

```
lis1 = [3 2 3 120 2 120]
lis2 = [50 20 60 98 27 99]
```

Y primero tengo que saber si en la primera hay un número repetido (eso lo he conseguido, o eso creo) y después tengo que comparar en la lista de abajo los números, es decir, el 3 esta repetido, entonces tengo que comparar el 50 y el 60, y eliminar el primer 3, ya que el 50 que es posicion[0] corresponde al primer 3, y tengo que ir eliminado los menores. 
Ejemplos de entrada y salida:

```
1 2 3 14 2 1
5 20 50 55 27 2
```

Salida:

```
1 3 14 2
```

En este caso me lo hace bien

```
1 2 2 2 3 4
5 20 22 21 60 5
```

Salida:

```
1 2 3 4
```

En mi caso lo hace mal ya que a mí me da `1 2 3`

```
3 2 3 120 2 120
50 20 60 98 27 99
```

Salida:

```
3 2 120
```

A mi me da lo siguiente: `2 120 2`

Este es mi código:

```
lista = input()
nivel = input()
resultado = lista.split()
lista = lista.split()
nivel = nivel.split()
# resu = []
for a in range(len(lista)):
   for b in range(a + 1, len(lista)):
     if lista[a] == lista[b]:
       if nivel[a] < nivel[b]:
         resultado.pop(a)
         # resu.append(lista[b])
       else:
         resultado.pop(b)
         # resu.append(lista[a])
print(resultado)
```

Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano!

Comment: La indentacion del código que has puesto está mal. Supongo que sea un problema del copia & pega. Mira aquí para hacerlo bien: https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE

Comment: Gracias! Es mi primer vez aquí y no lo sabía, está bien ahora? @abulafia

Comment: No entiendo muy bien a la comparación que e hace con la segunda linea ¿puedes poner la explicación completa del ejercicio?

Comment: Lo que hace es, buscar numeros repetidos, por ejemplo, en esta linea, 3 2 3 120 2 120, primero cogeria el primer 3 y segundo 3, que si lo pasamos a posiciones serían la [0] y la [2], entonces con eso tiene que comparar la posicion[0] y la posicion[2] de la segunda lista y eliminar el menor. Ejemplo:
3 2 3 120 2 120
50 20 60 98 27 99
Coge los 3, y elimina el 50 y el primer 3, despues elimina el primer 2 y despues elimina el primer 120, entonces la salida es:
3 2 120 
@solamente

Comment: @Sphere Perfecto voy a mirar como hacer ya lo entendi

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! @solamente

Comment: @Sphere ¿Lo sacaste también?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la solución que te propongo para tu problema estoy empezando con python así que puede que haya formas más optimas para realizar los loops. El problema que tenias es que planteaste solucionarlo quitando elementos de la lista cuando es mejor añadirlos a una nueva los que van a ser el resultado final.

```
lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 14, 2, 1]
lista2 = [5, 20, 50, 55, 27, 2]
result = []


def isMaxValue(listToCheck, indexVal1, indexVal2):
  if listToCheck[indexVal1] > listToCheck[indexVal2]:
    return True
  else:
    return False


for x in range(len(lista1)):
  maxValue = True
  y = 0
  while y < len(lista1):
    if lista1[y] == lista1[x] and x != y:
      if not isMaxValue(lista2, x, y):
        maxValue = False
    y += 1
  if maxValue:
    result.append(lista1[x])

print(result)
```

Modificado: Funciona para todos los casos

Comment: Ese caso lo hace bien, pero el siguiente:
lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 14, 2, 1]
lista2 = [5, 20, 50, 55, 27, 2]
No lo hace bien, muchas gracias por la ayuda igualmente! Voy a ver si consigo algo :D

Comment: @Sphere Cierto no probe todos los casos, lo he modificado y ahora si que esta para todos

Comment: FUNCIONA! Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema proviene de que, una vez que haces `resultado.pop(a)`, ya que has eliminado un elemento, todos los índices de la lista han cambiado.

Es decir, por ejemplo, si la lista tiene `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` el elemento de índice `2` es `"c"`. Pero si haces `lista.pop(1)` y para sacarle el de índice 1, ahora la lista quedaría `['a', 'c', 'd']` con lo que la `c` ya deja de ser la de índice 2.

Se me ocurre como solución que apenas modifica tu código lo siguiente. En lugar de eliminar con `pop()` el elemento, "márcalo" cambiando su valor con `None` por ejemplo. De ese modo no modificas el tamaño de la lista ni sus índices. Una vez que has terminado de marcarlos todos, el resultado será quedarse con los elementos distintos de `None` de esa lista.

O sea:

```
lista = input()
nivel = input()
resultado = lista.split()
lista = lista.split()
nivel = nivel.split()
# resu = []
for a in range(len(lista)):
   for b in range(a + 1, len(lista)):
     if lista[a] == lista[b]:
       if nivel[a] < nivel[b]:
         resultado[a] = None
       else:
         resultado[b] = None
resultado = [r for r in resultado if r is not None]
print(resultado)
```

He verificado que funciona bien para todos los casos de ejemplo que has puesto.

Answer (score 0):

modificando tu código lo menos posible seria de la siguiente manera:

```js
lis1 = [3, 2, 3, 120, 2, 120]
lis2 = [50, 20, 60, 98, 27, 99]
lisResultado = lis1.copy()
restar = 0;
for x in range((len(lis1) )):
  for y in range(x + 1, (len(lis1))):
    if(lis1[x] == lis1[y]):
      if(lis2[x] < lis2[y]):
        lisResultado.pop(x - restar)
      else:
        lisResultado.pop(y - restar)
      restar += 1
print(lisResultado)
```

Lo que pasaba es que cuando hacias `pop(pos)` de la array resultado, esta array perdia legth, mientras la array que recorrias mantenia se `legth` original. Eso quiere decir que en la array original el numero 3 ocupada pos 3, pero en resultado ocupapaba uno menos, por eso te eliminaba valor incorrecto. Lo solucione poniendo una variable auxiliar que resta el valor correcto.